# How to turn the first image into the second using python pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, data-science, data-analysis

I want to only keep the last location(level2) entry for every last name (eg:Balchunias,London etc). How do i do it?

I want to turn this:
[image]

to this:
[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df.loc[df.duplicated(['Location(level2)','Employee ID'], keep='last'), 'Location(level2)'] = ''
```